# Creating New ProjectType Netbeans Plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I am going thru official tutorials [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html) and [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html). It pretty much summarise how to provide support of new project template. Just one thing is not clear to me. I am trying to replicate screens of PHP plugins as given below:

**Selecting Project Category**

[image]

**Set path/Folers etc for Project Creation**

[image]

I exactly need these two screens. Is there some existing Dialog template that I can use or I have to create from scratch?